# Blank page removal

Tags: blank-page

I have two questions please:

(1) I have a blank page in my Latex document, and I don't know how to get rid of it.

(2) I don't understand why my Abstract has no title.

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{ociamthesis}  % default square logo 

\usepackage[bottom=37mm,top=30mm,left=33mm,right=33mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{aas_macros}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{changepage} % for temp adjustment of page margin
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[font={footnotesize}]{caption}
\let\oldtabular\tabular
\renewcommand{\tabular}{\footnotesize\oldtabular}

\include{mymacros}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}
\renewcommand*{\nompreamble}{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\renewcommand*{\nompostamble}{\end{multicols}}
\setlength{\columnsep}{3em}


\title{My Title}
\abstracttitle{Abstract Title}

\author{my name}             %your name
\college{my college}             %your college

\degreelevel{Degree}     %the degree
\degreedate{2015}         %the degree date

\DeclareMathSizes{12}{13}{8}{10}  % For size 12 text 

\begin{document}

\baselineskip=24pt plus1pt % this looks about double-line

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}


\maketitle                  % create a title page from the preamble info
\include{dedication} 
\newgeometry{bottom=2.4cm,top=2.2cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm}
\baselineskip=18pt plus1pt % this looks pretty good for the TOC
\include{acknowledgement}   % include an acknowledgements.tex file

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\include{declaration} % include a declaration.tex file    

\baselineskip=18pt plus1pt % Looks pretty good for the abstract etc.
\newgeometry{bottom=2.6cm,top=2.4cm,left=3cm,right=3cm}
\include{abstract}          % include the abstract

\begin{romanpages}          % start roman page numbering

\tableofcontents            % generate and include a table of contents
\newgeometry{bottom=2.4cm,top=2.2cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm}

\baselineskip=18pt plus1pt % this looks pretty good for the TOC
\listoffigures              % generate and include a list of figures
\listoftables              % generate and include a list of tables

\end{romanpages}                 % end roman page numbering

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\newgeometry{bottom=4cm,top=4cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm}
\baselineskip=24pt plus1pt % change back to normal spacing

\doublespacing

\include{chapter1} % Chapter1
\include{chapter2} % Chapter2
\include{chapter3} % Chapter3
\include{chapter4} % Chapter4
\include{chapter5} % Chapter5
\include{chapter6} % Chapter6
\include{conclusions} % Conclusions

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References} % changes bibliography name to references
\baselineskip=14pt plus1pt % compress the references a bit

\bibliographystyle{./aa}
\bibliography{./references}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where is the blank page? You should really think about the community when posting. We don't have any of your files you `\include`, and therefore can't adequately reproduce the "problem". How about removing all the unnecessary stuff from your code such that the problem still presents itself and using [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) and portable code that we can copy-and-paste? That's what we call a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). You've been here long enough to know how things work, right?

Comment: Sorry I don't often post about Latex - I don't understand it very well. My blank page is after the "List of Tables" and before "Chapter 1".

Comment: Under `twoside` you're opening every `\chapter` on an odd (recto or right) page. If there's nothing on the even (verso or left) page, then it'll be left blank. Is that what's happening?

Answer (score 2):

You should try adding the option `openany` to the `\documentclass` instruction:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openany]{ociamthesis}
```